# Converting binary to string

Tags: python-3.x, binary

I need to convert: 1010100 1101000 1101001 1110011 100000 1101001 1110011 100000 1100001 100000 1110011 1110100 1110010 1101001 1101110 1100111 to string.
I've converted string to binary

```
text2 = 'This is a string'
res = ' '.join(format(ord(i), 'b') for i in text2)

print(res)

#output:
1010100 1101000 1101001 1110011 100000 1101001 1110011 100000 1100001 100000 1110011 1110100 1110010 1101001 1101110 1100111
```

And now I've problem to converting it back to string, chr gives me some asian characters:

```
c = ' '.join(chr(int(val)) for val in res.split(' '))

print(c)
#output:
```

Then I try binascii but also not working:

```
l = res.split()
print(l)
for i in l:
    print (binascii.b2a_uu(bytes(i, 'utf-8')))
    output:
    b"',3 Q,#$P,   \n"
    b"',3$P,3 P,   \n"
    b"',3$P,3 P,0  \n"
    b"',3$Q,# Q,0  \n"
    b'&,3 P,# P\n'
    b"',3$P,3 P,0  \n"
    b"',3$Q,# Q,0  \n"
    b'&,3 P,# P\n'
    b"',3$P,# P,0  \n"
    b'&,3 P,# P\n'
    b"',3$Q,# Q,0  \n"
    b"',3$Q,#$P,   \n"
    b"',3$Q,# Q,   \n"
    b"',3$P,3 P,0  \n"
    b"',3$P,3$Q,   \n"
    b"',3$P,#$Q,0  \n"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "also not working"?

Comment: @ScottHunter You can see the output, it's still not 'This is a string'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `base` for `int`:

```
''.join(chr(int(val, 2)) for val in res.split(' '))
```

Output:

```
'This is a string'
```

Comment: What actually is this base "2"? I try to find more info to find out but can't find out.